# Is there any meaning to running -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,runtime when running Spring Boot locally?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, java-11, spring-profiles

In my team I frequently (>10) see Spring Boot projects with the following instructions for running locally:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,runtime
```

My understanding of [Spring Boot profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) is that each one corresponds to a particular environment, eg dev, test - so you would never need more than one. Also that each profile name corresponds to a particular env file - eg `src/main/java/resources/application-dev.yml` `application-test.yml` etc.

I would have thought that you would run the app on your local machine with:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

And have the local configuration in:

```
src/main/java/resources/application-local.yml
```

This is running:

- Java 11
- maven parent is `org.springframework.boot` `spring-boot-starter-parent` `2.2.6.RELEASE`
- maven version is 3.3.9

My question is: **Is there any meaning to running -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,runtime when running Spring Boot locally?**

Comment: It really depends on the architecture of the application. I assume they have the "dev" to support some devtools props and "local" would be so that their application doesn't need replicas. These are merely examples just to give you an idea what might be happening. Yes, in this case there is a meaning of *-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,runtime*

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. Could you please give an example of devtools props?

Comment: `spring.devtools.restart.include=abcd/**` will restart the application when changes are seen inside `abcd/**` files while you may or may not need this in production.